# Not getting the method to pass id and value of radio button as parameter with react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using React.Js with react-bootstrap.

What I am expecting when user click on radio button then the id and value of radio button should passed to some function so that I can do some operation with that values.

The radio button function

```
renderApptype = (data) =>  {
    if(data!=null){
      return (
        <tr key={data.id}>
          <td key={data.id}>
            <Radio name="radioGroup" id={data.id} onChange={ (id,value,e) => { this.sending(id,value,e) } } value={data.appType}>{data.appType}</Radio>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    }
  }
```

The function where i want the result.

```
sending = (id,value,e) => {
    console.log("id = ",id);
  }
```

Problem Not getting the method to pass id and value of radio button as parameter.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the callback function as:

```
(e) => { const {target: {id, value}} = e; this.sending(id, value, e); }
```

The `onChange` event, will call your function with just the `event` object as argument. So rest of the handling you need to do by yourself.

But, I will rewrite your function as

```
sending = (e) => {
  const {target: {id, value}} = e;
  console.log("id = ",id);
}
```

and keep the callback function clean, pass the just the function object as props value.

```
<Radio name="radioGroup" id={data.id} onChange={this.sending}.. />
```